# Fetch P4 file version in SQL File

Tags: perforce

I have some PL/SQL stored packages which get deployed by different teams on different servers. Its always a hassle if i have to check if the same version is deployed across all the servers.

What I want to do is to create a function in the given package that calling it will print the current version of the file.

Now the version of the file that I want to get printed is the version which is in P4. So What i am looking at that once I submit the file into perforce, perforce automatically update a certain variable with-in the file which corresponds to the current submitted version and in plsql, I can just print it.

How can I do this ?

---

Thanks to @cristobalito for referring to P4 [KB](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-RCS-Keywords)

I made a function in my package, something like this

```
FUNCTION get_script_version RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    changed_date    VARCHAR2(60)    :=  '$DateTime$';
    change_list     VARCHAR2(30)    :=  '$Change$';
    revision        VARCHAR2(30)    :=  '$Revision$';
    changed_by      VARCHAR2(50)    :=  '$Author$';
BEGIN
    RETURN changed_date||'  '||change_list||'  '||revision||'  '||changed_by;
END get_script_version;
```

Then, in P4 client

1: right click on your desired files and then right click to select "change filetype"
[image]

2: Then in new window, select on **k+** attributes
[image]

And submit the file. P4 will replace the $$ with respective values.

Comment: Perforce doesn't manipulate its file contents afaik, so it's impossible (without an external process) to embed such info. You used to be able to do this with CVS (keyword substitution - http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/cvs_16.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, done some further googling after comment above and apparently perforce does support keyword substitution as described [here](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Using-RCS-Keywords). That may get you some way towards what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It worked ... I am going to update my question with details so that other may get help from it as well